# How do I validate an enum value read from a file?

Tags: c, enums

If I am reading binary values from a file in C, then an integer that is supposed to be a member of an enum can be checked manually by looping through the enum itself and verifying that the integer is one of those values, but this seems like a somewhat tedious process. If I just cast the read value to the enum, then I assume some kind of runtime error will occur if the value is invalid.

Is there a better method of validating the enum than doing a manual check loop?

Note that in my case, the enum(s) in question do not necessarily have consecutive values, so min/max checking is not a solution.

Comment: Did you try it?

Comment: 1. show us your code (an example) if you want help to improve it; 2. enums are basically a comfortable way to name numeric values.  You won't get a runtime error when casting an integer to an enum (though you might loose data if the enum data uses less bits than the integer type)...

Comment: @user7176709: The question asks whether there is a better method. How does one try “Is there a better method?”?

Comment: @Myst: This is not a “What is wrong with this code?” question, so there is no need to supply sample code for it.

Comment: @EricPostpischil , the question asks for a better method - but without seeing the code, how can we tell? Is OP using a switch statement, if statements or a map (array)... true, example code isn’t required - but it would help.

Comment: @Myst: The question describes two methods: Manually checking each member of the enumeration and using a cast. Those suffice to frame the question.

Answer (score 4):

In C, all `enum`s are actually integral types.

So *any* value of that integral type is a valid value for your `enum`.

If you are careful and set up the `enum` labels so they are consecutive (the default is consecutive from 0), it's a simple case of checking if the value from the file is in that range. Otherwise, yes, it's tedious.

Comment: Is it specifically an `int` type? I recall it can be a smaller or larger integer type depending on the defined enums values?

Comment: @FireLancer: That's the C++ rule, not the C one (although I'm starting to doubt).

Comment: @FireLancer: I think you might be correct. I'll amend this answer.

Comment: In my case the enum values are not necessarily continuous.

Comment: @TylerDurden: Well you need to settle down to a fair bit of typing then.

Comment: So, from your code I gather that foo x = (foo)88 will not generate a runtime error, even though 88 is not a valid value.

Comment: @TylerDurden: What I'm trying to say is that 88 **is** a valid value, as far as the enumerator is concerned.

Comment: For my purposes, a "valid" value is one which is found in the enum. So if I have enum values 1, 2, 5 and 7, then only an integer having one of those values is part of the set of values in the enum and is valid.

Answer (score 4):

`enum` in C works like an integer, and so it can be forced to any value by any kind of read function taking a pointer, or directly casting it from integer types.

If the enum has only sequential values, some programs have a `max` enum value for their  enum. These can either have explicit values, or have the implicit values which will always start from `0` and go up sequentially. This way they can just check the value is in the allowed range (0 to `max - 1`), rather than checking it for every allowed value.

```
typedef enum foo { 
    foo_a,
    foo_b,
    foo_c,
    foo_max //last
} foo;
int main(void)
{
    foo x = (foo)88; // from somewhere
    if (x >= 0 && x < foo_max)
        printf("valid\n");
    else printf("invalid\n");
}
```

Comment: Upvoted as this has always been correct, and it's a nice way of doing this.

Comment: This isn't really major issue in this answer, but I would rather use `foo_end` or `foo_count` instead of `foo_max`. Maximum is typically *inclusive* boundary, and in this case it's used as *exclusive* boundary.